# Is there any simple way to initialize an object of MenuItem in android?

Tags: android, menu, menuitem, android-menu

Whenever i try to initialize a menu item i get to implement all these methods, I'm looking for a better way to initialize the MenuItem.

```
private MenuItem mMenuItem = new MenuItem() {
    @Override
    public int getItemId() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupId() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public MenuItem setTitle(final CharSequence charSequence) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public MenuItem setTitle(final int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getTitle() {
        return null;
    }

    ......  
};
```

Is there any possible way to avoid these long methods?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but if you want my opinion - a menu item will get added to a menu, and a menu would require all of these things to be implemented.

Comment: i'm trying to hide and show a menu item based on my program logic...how to initialize the menu item then?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better way to initialize the MenuItem !! here is the solution

1- first you have to create a custom Class that implements **MenuItem** then you implement all methods needed . as shown below :

```
public abstract class MenuItem2 implements MenuItem {

    @Override
    public int getItemId() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupId() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return 0;
    }
 .....
   @Override
    public MenuItem setOnActionExpandListener(OnActionExpandListener listener) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

2 - second you can use that custom Class **MenuItem2** and initialize only the method that you want .

```
 MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem2() {
            @Override
            public int getItemId() {
                return R.id.#####;
            }
        };
```